# How to decode from blob to plain text string?

Tags: apex

I have a rest apex call that take the body as blob, and then email it to someone:

```
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
string content = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(req.requestBody);
```

However it's encoded as this:

```
dGVzdCBlbWFpbA==
```

What I need is the plain text:

```
test email
```

How do I decode it back to plain text?

Here is decoding example:  https://www.base64decode.org/dec/dGVzdCBlbWFpbA==

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RestContext.request.requestBody` is a `Blob` body of the REST resource request. In order to convert `Blob` to `String` you can simply use `toString` method of the [Blob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm) class.

For example:

```
Blob someBlob = Blob.valueOf('text');
System.debug(someBlob.toString());
```

results in

> USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|text

---

applying it to your question, you want to have the following code:

```
String content = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
```

Comment: Getting this error : System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string